# Bloom error :Not a valid object name

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying bloom of my package.
git-bloom-release failed with "fatal: Not a valid object name".
What am I doing wrong?

my git-bloom-config:

```
Current bloom configuration:

[bloom]
upstream = https://github.com/Moirai/opt_camera-release.git
upstreamtype = git
upstreambranch = src/opt_camera
```

git-bloom-release rosdebian groovy:

```
###
### Running 'git bloom-import-upstream --replace'... 
###
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]: Searching in upstream development branch for the name and version
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]:   Upstream url:        https://github.com/Moirai/opt_camera-release.git
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]:   Upstream type: git
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]:   Upstream branch: src/opt_camera
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]: Checking for package.xml(s)
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]: package.xml(s) found
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]: Found upstream with version: 0.0.1
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]: Upstream contains package: opt_camera
 [git-bloom-import-upstream]: Exporting version 0.0.1
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git archive -o /tmp/bloom_J1Z4Au/upstream-0.0.1.tar 0.0.1'
 run at: '/tmp/bloom_J1Z4Au/upstream_repo'
 errcode: 128:
fatal: Not a valid object name
[/vcstools]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/git-bloom-release", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('bloom==0.2.16', 'console_scripts', 'git-bloom-release')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/release.py", line 127, in main
    ret = iu_main(iu_args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/import_upstream.py", line 599, in main
    retcode = import_upstream(cwd, tmp_dir, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/logging.py", line 122, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/import_upstream.py", line 497, in import_upstream
    import_orig(tarball_path, 'upstream', upstream_repo.get_url(), version)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/import_upstream.py", line 289, in import_orig
    targz = tarfile.open(tarball_path, 'r:gz')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1678, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1722, in gzopen
    fileobj = bltn_open(name, mode + "b")
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/bloom_J1Z4Au/upstream-0.0.1.tar.gz'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55088/bloom-error-:not-a-valid-object-name/) by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on 2013-02-14**:
This bloom error is caused by tag in my repository. I added a correct tag as below ;
git tag 0.0.1
git push --tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm not confident with this answer since it is not documented, but it seems your target repository (https://github.com/Moirai/opt_camera-release.git) needs "tag" named 0.0.1.

```
git clone https://github.com/Moirai/opt_camera-release.git
cd opt_camera-release
git tag 0.0.1
git push --tags
```

if this works, we can put this information as an enhancement at https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues.

Also, bloom assumes you have https://github.com/Moirai/opt_camera repository that only contains source directory (src/opt_camera in your case), and bloom tool will create opt_camera-release repository for you.

Best

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on 2013-02-14**:
Thanks for your advice.
This bloom error is caused by tag in my repository.
The git-bloom-release succeeded. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This particular error you are getting is due the fact that there is no tag which matches your version in your upstream repository.

More fundamentally, it looks like you are trying to use your upstream repository (the place where you keep your source code and do development) as your release repository.  This is not generally the case, usually you have you source code for a package (say foo) at a repository like `https://github.com/organization/foo.git` and then you have a separate repository called the release repository where you use bloom.  Normally this repository is named something like `foo-release`.

The appropriate work flow for bloom is that in the **release** repository you run `git-bloom-config <URL of the upstream repo> git` and then `git-bloom-release rosdebian groovy`.  This will get the latest version of your **upstream** (by way of a tag matching your version, e.g. `0.0.1`) and import it into the **release** repository.  Then it will generate the debian files required for the build farm to create binary debs of your package.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on 2013-02-14**:
Thanks for your detailed advice. I finished bloom of my catkin package. Thank you !!